# Android BroadcastReceiver returns zero

Tags: android, android-studio

I make a broadcast call on my Android 10 device, but it returns zero. I tried the suggested solutions but they didn't work. How can I solve it?

manifest

```
<application
        <receiver android:name=".ExampleReceiver" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.myapplication.Test"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
</application>
```

ExampleReceiver.java

```
public class ExampleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String test = "Hello World";
        setResultData(test);
    }

}
```

```
am broadcast -a com.example.myapplication.Test
Broadcasting: Intent { act=com.example.myapplication.Test flg=0x400000 }
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Documentation says

> If your app targets API level 26 or higher, you cannot use the
> manifest to declare a receiver for implicit broadcasts (broadcasts
> that do not target your app specifically), except for a few implicit
> broadcasts that are exempted from that restriction. In most cases, you
> can use scheduled jobs instead.

So you need to register your receiver in code.

```
registerReceiver(new ExampleReceiver(), new IntentFilter("com.example.myapplication.Test"));
```

[image: successful result picture]

Comment: Thank you it's working. How can I make it a background service? I want it to be running all the time. I need to use foreground service but I couldn't understand it.

@BashtanovProkhor